# Problem with wipers on 1993 Ford F150 302 v8 5.0 liter

Tags: electrical, ford, troubleshooting, windshield-wipers, f-150

I had a problem with my wipers. The motor was junk, so I replace the motor. I bolted it back on, plugged it back in, and it still doesn't work. I unplugged it and pushed the button for the wipers and I heard the click behind the glove compartment. I pulled the glove compartment out unscrewed two bolts on the big black box and the wiper control module is just behind that and it seems to be working properly at least it seems. I plugged the wiper motor back in and went to use my wipers. The clicking stopped, so I checked my fuse and everything was ok. Every time I try to use my wipers it doesn't work because the wiper control module doesn't click. The wiper control module only clicks when I have the wiper motor unplugged.

I have no idea what my problem is here, but when I plug in the motor, I have no power. I unplugged the motor and I have 12 volts at the source. I plugged it in and I have no power. Is my control module bad? Or is the blinker switch bad? I took the motor back to O'Reilly's and had it checked; the motor is good.

Comment: PUHLEESE use some punctuation.

Comment: Lmfao sorry I was getting pissed working on my truc.  so I came in and just wrote it I'm not on a computer. I'm on my phone. I don't use punctuation very much

Answer (score 1):

How did you know the original wiper motor was "junk"? Did you test it before you replaced? Since the new motor tests good, I think the two areas you have pointed to (wiper control module or blinker switch) are good places to start. Since you can hear the box click and there's power at the box when you flip the blinker switch, it's my hunch the problem lies in the box, not the switch.